# What URL should I use for Google Home local execution app

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, local, google-smart-home

I'm trying the sample project for google home local execution https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-local

Is the URL README file correct?

> In Develop > Actions > On device testing set the development URL to http://local-dev-server-hostname-or-ip:8080/

It seems that the google home device is sending a get request to "/" and nothing is deployed at "/", the app said the URL is:

```
[local-home-app] Node ondevice testing URL:   http://192.168.101.69:8080/node/bundle.js
[local-home-app] Chrome ondevice testing URL: http://192.168.101.69:8080/web/index.html
```

```
Frame 19273: 694 bytes on wire (5552 bits), 694 bytes captured (5552 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: f0:72:ea:88:8b:30 (f0:72:ea:88:8b:30), Dst: Raspberr_7e:77:5d (dc:a6:32:7e:77:5d)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.101.63, Dst: 192.168.101.69
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 38838, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 138161, Ack: 85361, Len: 628
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
[Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
[GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
[Severity level: Chat]
[Group: Sequence]
Request Method: GET
Request URI: /
Request Version: HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.101.69:8080\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux aarch64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.81 Safari/537.36 CrKey/1.42.180404\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3\r\n
CAST-DEVICE-CAPABILITIES: {"audio_assistant":true,"bluetooth_supported":true,"display_supported":false,"hi_res_audio_supported":false,"remote_control_input_supported":false,"touch_input_supported":false}\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Accept-Language: en-us,en\r\n
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://192.168.101.69:8080/]
[HTTP request 221/222]
[Prev request in frame: 19227]
[Response in frame: 19274]
[Next request in frame: 19312]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Actions console now supports two development testing URLs due to [new device support](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/local-home-sdk-support-on-google-nest-wifi.html) for Local Home SDK:

- Testing URL for Chrome
- Testing URL for Node

For the local development server packaged with the sample, this corresponds to the Chrome and Node URLs printed when you start the server instance.